# How can I project an object to a sphere

Tags: modeling

My problem is, I don't know how to do a projection of an object to a sphere, 
without making particle system.

If you don't understand my question, this is what I would like to do:

[image]
Project this landscape into the interior of the sphere.

It's like in the intro of Game of Thrones, there is an interior sphere with the map in 3d.

Edit: This is how it should look like: [image]

But the method I used to do that is... a [cloth simulation](https://framapic.org/71FcFJEqAMIi/6YvqNWwzbnW7.gif/), this is not the best method, since it destroys all.

Comment: I agree with cegaton about the camera distortion, concerning the part of the question about the Game of Thrones intro. Aside from that, there are many ways to get the spherical shape, Hook modifier is one of them, curve modifier is another.

Comment: Are you trying to texture one mesh with the other mesh?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can do this with a lattice and shrinkwrap modifiers.

Starting with a scene like this:

A landscape and a hemisphere

[image]

Add a lattice object, make it so it has only 1 subdivison on the W axis.
In edit mode make resize the lattice it so that it is slightly larger than the landscape.

[image]

Place the lattice so that it lays under your landscape, not touching but the very bottom vertices of the object.

[image]

Then select the landscape, add a lattice modifier and select the lattice as deforming object.

[image]

Select the lattice object and add a shrinkwrap modifier to it. Set the hemisphere as Target. Change the Mode to Project, Direction to negative on the Z axis.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

NOTE:

The original question asked how to do distortion like the opening scene on the TV series *Games of Thrones*, so this answer was to give an alternate way to think about how the landscape scene were done...

I'll leave the answer up. Maybe someone will find it useful.

If what you are looking for is the distortion over the landscape, this can be done with a wide angle lens and a lens distortion node:

[image]

[image]

This is just the camera travelling over a flat landscape with 10mm lens, using a shallow depth of field and using a lens distortion node.

Comment: Yeah I think this method was used for the intro of the Game of Thrones, but still it's an interesting question the way OP describes it

Comment: No this is not what i would like to do, i would like to do something that looks like more like that :  [link](https://framapic.org/71FcFJEqAMIi/6YvqNWwzbnW7.gif)  But here the method i used is cloth simulation, it destroy all the shapes of the landscape : [link](https://framapic.org/KGLNBHq71Vb3/ckiOnjNgsa0W.png)