# Wrapping Landscape to a Sphere

Tags: modeling, uv

I am currently working on a research project where we are making full sized models of Mars and the Moon. I am looking for the best way to wrap a landscape (preferably given through a height map) around a sphere. The user cegaton answered this in a pretty general way as seen here:
([How can I project an object to a sphere](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/55552/how-can-i-project-an-object-to-a-sphere)) but I was wondering if anyone could provide a more step by step instruction process for I am a new user.

Thank you all very much.

Comment: Hi, that linked answer was already quite detailed, why not try to follow it, and come here to explain what isn't working for you: lattice? shrinkwrap?

Comment: A research project, so you should have some specifications, what level of precision do you need for your positionning, what kind of image do you have as input? Shrinkwrap is a good solution to project something on an object, but the if you need to apply a texture to a sphere with a good positionning without loosing to mush resolution on some points, uv mapping will be more accurate. You will also be able to use the Displace modifier to use your height map, using displacement with the same shape of your base texture, using the same uv unwrap.

Comment: Thie is a question that gets asked quite often, see the following links: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/24043/how-to-animate-morphing-a-rectangular-plane-into-a-sphere/24053#24053 and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/13898/morph-targets-a-sphere-shape-turning-into-a-cylindrical-unwrapped-sphere-shape/13927#13927  and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10741/what-is-the-best-way-to-unwrap-a-sphere and https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/3315/how-to-get-perfect-uv-sphere-mercator-projection

Answer (score 1):

This is a really simple task.
If you have an equirectangular height map, just use the Displacement modifier using the texture as input on a high-resolution sphere.

[image]